# Can't restart node after deleting all data in Ledger and Accounts directories

Tags: validator

I probably went about resetting my node the wrong way, but I don't know where to go from here.  I had the node running, but needed to change the indexing settings.  So I shut it down, then deleted all data in the Ledger and Accounts directories.

I expected that it would simply try to download the snapshot again and start over, but I keep getting the error:

```
[solana_accounts_db::hardened_unpack] Failed to open ledger genesis_config at "/mnt/ledger": Unable to open "/mnt/ledger/genesis.bin": Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }, IO error: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Does anyone know how to make it stop looking for this file and just start over?

Comment: Can you provide your full startup command? It's tough to tell just from the error